# JS, Searching in array doesnt work

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
 0. <script type="text/javascript">
 1.   var games = new GameList("bets");
 2.   games = games.getGames(); //an Array, example: games = ("1313_55", "3353_65");
 3.   
 4.   var game_ids = $.map(games, function(_g) {     
 5.     return _g.split('_')[0];
 6.   });
 7.   
 8.   idsList = game_ids.join(",");
 9.   var _srch = -1;
10.   for(var i = 0, j = idsList.length; i < j && _srch == -1; i++)
11.   {
12.     _srch = idsList.search(/ids[i]/i);
13.   }
14. </script>
```

line 12 doesnt work. any ideas?
well line 12 works, but does not return the result correctly.

what i am trying to do:
Example:

I am searching a name in string :

```
var str = "my name is VuRaL"; 
_srch = str.search(/VuRaL/i);
```

//thats what i want to do.

**str.search(/VuRaL/i);** 
only VuRaL needs to be an array value like ids[1] etc.

Example: str.search(/ids[i]/i);

Thanks!

Comment: Agreed with @John's answer. What's with all the string splitting and joining?

Comment: Please forget the splits and joinings, Its long and hard to explain all the things there. I am using ids and pins in one array and saving them all in one cookie (as array).

Comment: games is array and contains = Array("1234_12", "3333_44", "5555_4"); ids is array and contains = Array("1234", "3333", "5555");

Comment: You really should explain: 1. What you expect and 2. What you get. Simply saying "it doesn't work" is useless if we don't know what "work" is supposed to be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`/ids[i]/` is a regex literal. It's not actually inserting the value of the variable `i`. Also, `[` and `]` have [special meaning](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#Using_Special_Characters) in JavaScript regexes, so you need to escape them. Replace line 12 with this:

```
_srch = idsList.search(new RegExp('ids\\[' + i + '\\]', 'i'));
```

Comment: just put ) at the end. I ll check it now

Comment: I'm looking at your code again and it's just not making sense. Line 12 is searching for strings that match things like `'ids[0]'`, `'ids[1]'`, `'ids[2]'`... you must be trying to solve the wrong problem here. Do you mind editing your question to include the actual problem this code is attempting to solve?

Comment: Matt example: I am searching a name in string : var str = "my name is VuRaL"; _srch = str.search(/VuRaL/i); thats all i wanted to do.

Answer (score 1):

Um.  Line 8 converts your array into a string.  Line 10 has you iterating over this string on a character by character basis.  Are you trying to find something in the overall string?  You don't need your for(){} loop if so.

Comment: I am searching for double values and i think this is faster then using 2 loops (IMO) and the IDS are dynamic.

Comment: @Vural Acar - Generally, no.  Your regex will likely be slower than a simple double loop iteration.  Although fewer lines of code implies faster, it doesn't always hold true.  However, I think I'm confused as to what you're trying to do.  What's in the ids array?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're going for?

```
 _srch = idsList.search(new RegExp("ids[" + i + "]", 'i'));
```

In case you want to search for brackets themselves, you'll need to escape them like so:

```
_srch = idsList.search(new RegExp("ids\\[" + i + "\\]", 'i'));
```

Comment: Syntaxerror in regular expression. Can you correct it please`?

Comment: @Vural: Sorry, I believe `i` is supposed to be a string. Try the above code again.